# How can I set the default namespace to the Rancher catalog apps with Helm?

Tags: rancher

I configured my Rancher to use helm3 chart to launch a new app to a current namespace.
In the Rancher Catalog Apps UI, the default namespace is not good, it does not belong to any existing available namespaces, I would like to find a way to set the default value with a specific kubenetes cluster's namespace.

By the official document below, I don't know if there is a way to change the default value...

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.0-v2.4/en/helm-charts/launching-apps/#launching-a-catalog-app
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an annotation for this in your Helm Chart in Chart.yaml:

```
annotations:
  catalog.cattle.io/namespace: yournamespace
```

You find all Chart.yaml annotations: [Here](https://docs.ranchermanager.rancher.io/how-to-guides/new-user-guides/helm-charts-in-rancher/create-apps)